# Join query error unknown index

Tags: php, mysql

Where i am wrong on this query result can someone help me.

```
<?php

include 'dbconfig.php';
$sql = 'SELECT SUM(total_fund.total_funds), total_fund .name from total_fund join project 
        WHERE total_fund.funds_id = project.project_id AND project_id=1200 GROUP BY project.project_id';
$retval = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql);

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($retval)) {

    echo $data['total_funds'] . '</br>';
    echo $data['name'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like: `SELECT fields FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.field = table2.field WHERE conditions`? (Notice I used `ON`)

Comment: Also, make sure that you are using the correct column names in the join. You used `total_fund.funds_id = project.project_id`, but they don't seem like related columns.

Comment: what is dot name ?

Comment: had to mouse wheel zoom in. There is a typo space early on

Comment: @FirstOne thats my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your query:

```
total_fund .name
```

should be written as:

```
total_fund.name
```

and you probably need an `AS` alias, anyway it's better to write your query this way:

```
select
  total_fund.name
  SUM(total_fund.total_funds) as total_funds
from
  total_fund join project on total_fund.funds_id = project.project_id
where
  project_id=1200
group by
  total_fund.name
```

Comment: query is right but error only alias naming so i completed my query. thankyou @fthiella

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete query

```
<?php

include 'dbconfig.php';
$sql = 'SELECT SUM(total_fund.total_funds)AS total, total_fund .name, project.Amount_to_be_raised from total_fund join project 
        where total_fund.funds_id = project.project_id AND project_id=1200';
$retval = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql);

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($retval)) {

    echo $data['total'] . '</br>';
    echo $data['name'];
}
?>
```